# How to align an image with text below?

Tags: html, css

I have an image which I want to align with the edge of text below. The text below is centered, but I can't figure out how keep it aligned on the left.
The code I have is:

```
<img src="Logo.png" style="margin: auto"/> 
<h1 style="text-align: center;>The Collaborative Observer</h1> 
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 100%; padding-left: 6cm">The best thing that has happened to ICE since ICE.</p>
```

I also use the padding feature to align the bottom text, and I am wondering if there is a better way to do that.
The code above is modified for color, but looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just simply insert `<center><img src="Logo.png" style="margin: auto"/></center>`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

when img & text in one div box, must set the 'vertical-align:text-bottom',so that the text under the image. sorry my English

```html
<style>
.logo-box{display: table; text-align: center;}
.logo-box img{height: 100px; width: 100px; vertical-align:text-bottom}
</style>

<div class="logo-box">
 <img src="Logo.png" /> 
 <h3>The Collaborative Observer</h3> 
</div>
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 100%; padding-left: 6cm">The best thing that has happened to ICE since ICE.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use of `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`.

From *HTML5 Doctor*:

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document.
>
> The figure element can be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings, etc., that are referenced in the main content of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the document, be moved away from that primary content — e.g., to the side of the page, to dedicated pages, or to an appendix.

So why not...

```
<figure>
    <img src="Logo.png" style="margin: auto"/>
    <figcaption>
        <h1>The Collaborative Observer</h1> 
        <p>The best thing that has happened to ICE since ICE.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

`<figure>` and `<figcaption>` are both block-level elements, so they will take up the full width of their container unless otherwise specified. This will allow the caption below to stretch to the edge of the element on each side, and then image will then be lined up correctly. Then add the following to your CSS file...

```
figure img {
    margin: auto;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
figcaption p {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-left: 6cm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted :

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="left:10%;display:inline;margin:0 auto;">
    <img src="http://almadaenmisr.com/templates/logo/1410252800_1266901625.jpg" width="100px" style="" />
  </div>
  <h1 style="display:inline;">The Collaborative Observer</h1> 
  <br />
  <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 100%;padding-left: 15%;display:inline;">The best thing that has happened to ICE since ICE.</p>

</div>
```

`Float` the image left & `inline` the text.

Though this is working code, I would like to suggest using frameworks like bootstrap/skeleton for design so that its easier to work with and also makes it readily usable with all screen sizes.

Comment: It is what I want on the small page, but when I go to full page it no longer looks like that. Is there anyway to keep it like that no matter what?

Comment: On a bigger page the logo is on the left, title is next to it & the text under it goes towards the side. How would you like it?

Comment: I want the logo and title centered, with the text under it, but a little to the right so that they end at the same line.